# Fit piecewise function

Tags: plotting, fitting, piecewise

I want to fit my data with the following function

```
     data={{1.56514, 
  0.000386675}, {1.5692, -0.000928546}, {1.57328, -0.000310485}, \
{1.57738, 0.000250999}, {1.5815, 0.00102017}, {1.58565, 
  0.0021676}, {1.58981, 0.00265123}, {1.594, 0.00256005}, {1.59821, 
  0.00220896}, {1.60244, 0.00357191}, {1.6067, 0.00461152}, {1.61097, 
  0.00582039}, {1.61527, 0.0071352}, {1.61959, 0.00964613}, {1.62394, 
  0.0143126}, {1.62831, 0.0180241}, {1.6327, 0.0219753}, {1.63712, 
  0.0264127}, {1.64156, 0.0340527}, {1.64602, 0.0366497}, {1.65051, 
  0.0411284}, {1.65503, 0.0425288}, {1.65956, 0.0476831}, {1.66413, 
  0.0480013}, {1.66872, 0.0511033}, {1.67333, 0.0487283}, {1.67797, 
  0.0504302}, {1.68263, 0.0472349}, {1.68732, 0.0459812}, {1.69204, 
  0.0414073}, {1.69679, 0.0419639}, {1.70156, 0.0355914}, {1.70635, 
  0.0368724}, {1.71118, 0.0341109}, {1.71603, 0.0308359}, {1.72091, 
  0.0275538}, {1.72582, 0.026369}, {1.73075, 0.0218431}, {1.73572, 
  0.0228733}, {1.74071, 0.0148684}, {1.74573, 0.0153343}, {1.75078, 
  0.011034}, {1.75586, 0.00504831}, {1.76097, 0.00569223}, {1.76611, 
  0.00855227}, {1.77127, 0.0114607}, {1.77647, 0.00478334}, {1.7817, 
  0.00792828}, {1.78696, 
  0.00736984}, {1.79226, -0.000310405}, {1.79758, 
  0.0016728}, {1.80293, -0.00132529}, {1.80832, 
  0.00223036}, {1.81374, -0.00358933}, {1.81919, -0.00287704}, \
{1.82468, -0.00264672}, {1.83019, -0.00992204}, {1.83575, \
-0.00291318}, {1.84133, -0.00611995}, {1.84695, -0.00471651}, \
{1.8526, -0.00341859}, {1.85829, -0.00830599}, {1.86402, \
-0.00572138}, {1.86977, -0.00872727}, {1.87557, -0.00653947}, \
{1.8814, -0.00546597}, {1.88727, -0.00958755}, {1.89317, \
-0.00221121}, {1.89911, -0.00185892}, {1.90509, -0.00146911}, \
{1.9111, -0.00560086}, {1.91716, -0.0148673}, {1.92325, -0.0102136}, \
{1.92938, -0.00885371}, {1.93555, -0.00745859}, {1.94176, \
-0.00467536}, {1.94801, -0.000528471}, {1.9543, -0.00494786}, \
{1.96063, -0.0129759}, {1.967, -0.00538248}, {1.97342, -0.00994746}, \
{1.97987, -0.00828132}, {1.98637, -0.00477076}, {1.99291, \
-0.00604739}, {1.9995, -0.00224111}, {2.00612, -0.0104317}, {2.0128, \
-0.00476654}, {2.01951, 
  0.00131814}, {2.02627, -0.0154254}, {2.03308, -0.0100921}, \
{2.03993, -0.0126969}, {2.04683, -0.00726984}, {2.05378, \
-0.00331492}, {2.06077, -0.00581028}, {2.06781, -0.00804149}, \
{2.0749, -0.000205423}, {2.08204, -0.00766642}, {2.08923, \
-0.00562204}, {2.09646, -0.00330615}, {2.10375, 0.00178708}, {2.11109,
   0.00492353}, {2.11848, -0.00464684}, {2.12592, -0.00158697}, \
{2.13341, -0.00893977}, {2.14096, -0.00948912}, {2.14856, \
-0.00635145}, {2.15622, -0.00665673}, {2.16393, -0.000782473}, \
{2.17169, -0.00867846}, {2.17951, 
  0.000185925}, {2.18739, -0.00699891}, {2.19532, 
  0.000991768}, {2.20332, 
  0.00696767}, {2.21137, -0.00152176}, {2.21948, -0.00232919}, \
{2.22764, -0.00941224}, {2.23587, -0.000394529}, {2.24416, \
-0.00322749}, {2.25252, -0.00161979}, {2.26093, -0.0066133}, {2.26941,
   0.00406229}, {2.27795, -0.00898485}, {2.28656, 
  0.00380425}, {2.29523, 0.00848942}, {2.30397, 
  0.00364964}, {2.31277, -0.00764645}, {2.32164, 
  0.00284468}, {2.33058, -0.000152509}, {2.33959, -0.0171756}, \
{2.34867, -0.00914236}, {2.35782, -0.0166113}}


eq= Piecewise[{{1/(1 + Exp[(1.65 - x)/d])*x^2*Exp[(-(x - mu)/(k*T))]*
 A*1/(s*Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-(1/2) ((x - mu)/s)^2], 
x < 1.67}, {Sqrt[(x - 1.65 - d)/(4 d)]*x^2*Exp[(-(x - mu)/(k*T))]*
 A*1/(s*Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-(1/2) ((x - mu)/s)^2], x >= 1.67}}]


k = 8.617 * 10^\[Minus]5; 



nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  eq, {mu, s, T, d, A}, x, 
  Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}]
```

To me it looks everything fine, but Mathematica reports the following error:

```
**1/2 ((-0.0511033+eq[0.987641,0.284773,-0.259993,0.349234,0.989531])^2+\
(-0.0504302+eq[0.987641,0.284773,-0.259993,0.349234,0.989531])^2+(-0.\
0487283+eq[0.987641,0.284773,-0.259993,0.349234,0.989531])^2+(-0.\
0480013+eq[0.987641,0.284773,-0.259993,0.349234,0.989531])^2+<<44>>+(-\
0.00256005+eq[0.987641,0.284773,-0.259993,0.349234,0.989531])^2+(-0.\
00223036+eq[0.987641,0.284773,-0.259993,0.349234,0.989531])^2+<<81>>) \
is not a real number at {mu,s,T,d,A} = \
{0.349234,0.987641,-0.259993,0.284773,0.989531}**
```

What I have is basically a gaussian which is quite broad in the high energy side and I would like to get the information of the peak position and the temperature coming from the tail. If you have also other suggestion for the function, please share! So far, this is the only method I found (and it does not work).

Best and thank you in advance

I did manage to have the function working but the fit depends a lot on the starting values. Any suggestion on how improve it?

[image]

Comment: There are two things:  (1) `k` isn't defined and (2) Evaluating `eq` with the default starting value of 1 for all parameters results in imaginary numbers (which is what the error message is saying).  So defining k (unless it, too, is a parameter) and better starting values should help.

Comment: My mistake, k was defined. I forgot to put it in the code. I will upload it. Now the code seems to working, but it is very dependent on the starting value. I have to be already very precise otherwise it's giving unphysical results. How can I improve on that?

Comment: The culprit is `Sqrt[(x - 1.65 - d)/(4 d)]`.  You've got to make sure that gives you a real value.  One way to guess at that is executing `Reduce[(# - 1.65 - d)/(4 d) > 0 & /@ {1.67, Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, d]` which gets you `0 < d < 0.02` (i.e., a restriction for `d` that you need to include.

Comment: By "working" it appears you mean "not giving errors" as opposed to "ending up with a reasonable fit".  What starting values are you using?  Are any of the parameter values approximately known?

Comment: I guess, in current case the best way is dividing the range into two and search for separate approximations. Quasi-gaussian function will fit well the left side and exponential decay will fit the right one. The optimal coefficients of these fits will serve as the initial values for of the joint approximation by your complicated function

Comment: Rom38, do you mean fitting the same data first with one function and then with another one?